# How send signed email with attachment

Tags: c#, email, x509certificate, email-attachments

I have method, which sign my email by certificate. This work fine if the line with adding an attachment is commented out.

```
private static void mailer()
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("test@email.cz");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("test@email.cz");

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

        message.Subject = "Test subject email";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        string body = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit \r\n\r\n";
        body += " Email body signed by certificate ";

        byte[] messageData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
        SignedCms Cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(messageData));

        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\TFS\cert_test.p12", "password");

        if (cert != null)
        {
            csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Valid certificate was not found");
        }

        CmsSigner Signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, cert);
        Cms.ComputeSignature(Signer);
        byte[] SignedBytes = Cms.Encode();
        MemoryStream signedStream = new MemoryStream(SignedBytes);
        AlternateView signedView = new AlternateView(signedStream, "application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name=sig.p7m");
        message.AlternateViews.Add(signedView);

        ContentType contentType = new ContentType();
        contentType.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
        contentType.Name = "test.xml";
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileData);
        ms.Position = 0;
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(ms, contentType);
        //message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.server.net");
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("smtp.server.net", "password", "user");

        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

But I must add attachments (3 or more) to email. When I add an attachment (just one attachment yet), the email no longer shows as signed and the body of email doesn't show up. I find some samples of my problem, but it useless for me.

I don't encrypt the body of email and an attachment. I need only sign an email by certificate.

Thanks for help.

EDIT: Sorry, I had commented out the line with adding signed AlternateView. Right commented out the line is with adding attachment to the email.

Comment: Maybe signing _after_ adding the attachments? Or signing the attachments, too?

Comment: Order signing and adding the attachments have no effect. It is one. I'm going to try signing the attachments.

Comment: So, signing the attachments is useless. I think that sign only the body of email. I'm wrong?